# Keep getting this error can not find symbol for exception

Tags: java, generics

```
 public E remove() throws EmptyContainerException
 {
  if(stuff.size() > 0)
  {
     return  stuff.remove(stuff.size() - 1);
  }
  else
  {
      throw new EmptyContainerException(); 
  }
 }
```

> getting not symbol not found errors for exception.. Do i need to make a class file for this exception?

Comment: Yes, where else could it come from?

Comment: I don't know, are you missing an [`import jdsl.core.api.EmptyContainerException`](https://cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/doc/jdsl/core/api/EmptyContainerException.html)?